# git pull and skip file that I already have locally

Tags: git

Say I have the below setup

```
mkdir repo1
touch repo1/file{1,2}
cd repo1
git init
git add *
git commit -am first
cd ..

mkdir repo2
cp repo1/file1 repo2/ # <<< important
cd repo2
git init
git remote add origin ../repo1
```

Now if I run the below git pull in repo2

```
git pull origin master
```

I get the error:

```
From ../repo1
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    file1
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I want to tell git to just use the `file1` copy in `repo2` that I've already downloaded instead of getting it again. I already know that git uses hardlinks to avoid duplicating files when cloning locally to save disk space. My situation is that I've already performed the copy and don't want to delete `repo2/file1` to keep going.

Comment: Not sure, but since seems to be two different repositories, it is not clear what are you doing. And if it's an untracked file, you first have to commit it, and then, manage eventually the merge.

Comment: You have the options, commit the file, delete the file, or clone the repo instead of copying.

Comment: @RobyB you're right. I just committed it and let the merge take care of it

Comment: note : the hardlink part only relates to some files under the `.git/` directory, not for checked out files.

Comment: Git doesn't know that local file1 is copy of file1 in remote repository, so as RobyB says you can commit this file. Else you can try hardlink manually.

Answer (score 1):

Since they seem to be two different repositories, probably, if the file it's untracked, you first have to commit it, and then, manage eventually the merge.

Answer (score 0):

So based on @RobyB, I just committed the file and then let the merge figure out that the file already exists.

```
cd repo2
git add file1
git commit -am 'add file1'

git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

At this stage, the git log looks a bit different, but a squash would do:

```
# git log
commit eec8 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: 61be626 beeefd6
Date:   Wed Sep 15 09:23:40 2021 -0400

    Merge branch 'master' of ../repo1

commit 61be62
Date:   Wed Sep 15 09:23:13 2021 -0400

    add file1

commit beeef (origin/master)
Date:   Wed Sep 15 09:09:58 2021 -0400

    first
```

Comment: Ok,  @shadi ! :D So could you vote up my comment then, if it helped ? Many  thanks : D

Comment: Did it. You could post your own answer if you want, and I'll just remove mine in favor of yours.

Comment: Actually what I  would have done is probably add the file and stash. Then after the pull I would just restore the file from the stash.

Comment: @matt that would definitely sort out the merge, but it wouldn't serve my purpose of avoiding a re-transmittal of the file since I already have a local copy.

Comment: Is that really true? A blob is a blob, its hash is its hash, if you already have this file in the repo it's in the repo and won't be "retransmitted".

Comment: you're proposing to do the pull first. That's what transmits the file in the first round.